# Error while pushing a std::pair in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-pair

I found doing a push in

```
Template < class a, class b > 
std::vector < std::pair < a, b > >::push_back(...)
```

almost always creates a segmentation fault.

I looked around for a bit and found there was an error being raised from `stl_uninitialized.h` (line 269).

The easiest work around I found was to reserve required / some large space for the vector and then do the push back. It worked but I'm not convinced. Why would there be an error

(My initial code is not even templated. It was with the fields

```
std::pair < float, cv::RotatedRect >
```

I templated here for people to be able to give generic answers).

Declaration of localDetections :

> std::vector < std::vector < std::pair < float, cv::RotatedRect> > >
>   localDetections;
>   localDetections.resize(m_allSizes.size());

where m_allSizes is a vector of no. of sizes that will be used to search and populate . Also the for condition is :

> for (int sit = 0 ; sit < m_allSizes.size(); sit++) {

Place where it is used :

> ```
>               cv::RotatedRect oupRect;                                                                                          
>               cv::Point2d src_center(img.cols/2., img.rows/2.);                                                                 
>               rotateRectInSpace(newRect, oupRect, src_center, -(rotatedAngle));                                                 
>               std::pair<float, cv::RotatedRect> newPair((float)finval, oupRect);                                      
>
>               localDetections[sit].push_back(newPair);
> ```

sit is a variable in for loop which goes from 0 through the size of localDectections.

Comment: Chances are you screwed up the copy or move constructor which causes the crash. Reserving space just means that no objects need to be moved or copied for a long time but does not fix the actual problem.

Comment: Can you show the lines of your exact code when you create your `pair` and try to `push_back`?

Comment: `Why would there be an error`  A bug in your code?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: Where do you allocate the elements for `localDetections[sit]`?

Comment: edited. That has been taken care of already. The problem does not happen in the beginning. It happens sometime during the run and though I know the exact place where it happens (push_back), which iteration of push_back is variable. Sometimes after 1 sec and other times after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential bug in your code where `sit` could overflow into negative numbers.  You may want to convert `sit` to be `vector::size_type`, or just use iterators, or `push_back` vectors onto localDetections as part of your loop instead of resizing beforehand.

Alternatively, something bad may be going on when you are trying to copy or assign `cv::RotatedRect oupRect`.

There are a lot of unknowns on this one.  There's nothing obviously wrong with the code posted.  A debugger is going to help more than StackOverflow.

Comment: No, I make sure sit is within correct bounds. So I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong there. 
However yeah, cv::RotatedRect might be a big cause here as the error occurs when I try to push the pair in vector inside a vector (localDetections). I thought about that too. Heck i even put conditions on RotatedRect so it is not empty point but even that didn't work either. I'll probably at this point try valgrind. I think its more of a dynamic memory issue than anything else. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for **locaDetections** first, using localDetections.resize or something like that.

localDetections needs to contains at least **sit** positions allocated before you call:

```
localDetections[sit].push_back(newPair);
```

Comment: Yeah I've already done that !
localDetections.resize(m_allSizes.size());